# Dashboard says max upload file size is 40MB but whenever I try and upload more than 8MB I get "HTTP Error"

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed a plugin "Upload Max File Size" which supposedly increased the maximum file size upload to 40MB. The default was 8MB. When I upload files through the Media -> add new in the dashboard, it works fine when it's <=8Mb but whenever it's bigger than that I get

```
HTTP Error
```

My php.ini file says

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 33M
```

php5.ini

```
post_max_size = 33M
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 33M
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 33M
```

Unfortunately I cannot access / edit the ini files though.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: HTTP error is kinda generic. No more details to share?

Comment: @Masiorama thats honestly the error it gives. When I upload files >8mb (more than the default) i get the error. Less than 8mb no error. In the media upload page it says Maximum upload file size: 39MB.

Comment: Well, you actually gave me another detail, that in media page it says that maximum upload file size is 39... that is strange indeed.

Comment: have you tried adding some @ini_set inside your theme?

Comment: @Masiorama I just tried that...i can't save my changes in the editor though...I have limited access to this webpage

Comment: Editor? You mean web editor? Can't you access the source code pages directly?

Comment: @Masiorama yes the editor in the dashboard. i cannot access the source code directly

Comment: Mmm that doesn't help at all. Sorry but you need to get the sources... and avoid experimenting this way on production environment. For your sake :)

Comment: @Masiorama I just edited the theme's function file, by creating a copy of it and uploading it in the same directory.

Comment: @Masiorama I added function increase_max_file_upload() 
{
    @ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '40M' );
    @ini_set( 'post_max_size', '40M');
    @ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
} and add_action('file_increase', 'increase_max_file_upload'); to the file...did not change anything

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any clue now.